# Angular mono repo compileroption different in libraries

Tags: angular, npm, monorepo

I have a mono repo structure for an angular project like this

```
MyProject/
  --myApp/
      --...
  --libs/
      --lib1/
        --...
      --lib2/
        --...
```

And my app is using those libraries, and in tsconfig for myApp I have set "compilerOptions strict:false", but on the tsconfig for the lib1 i have set "compilerOptions strict:true". Now, in case of building "myApp", it shows me the errors of "lib1" that are related with strict true.But when i run nx serve for "myApp" it doesn't show me the errors from "lib1".

It is possible for nx serve "myApp" to remain strict:false but also to show for some certain libraries the strict errors? How can i do this?